# VB.net 2013 use report viewer without dataset/source

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I'm using vb.net 2013.
I need to use the report viewer function but without linking any databases/sets/sources. 
I just need to print out some internally calculated info in the report.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using `Crystal Reports` ?

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ no i'm trying to use the built in datareporting function. I tried printform but I am unable to select the printer. It just prints to the default printer. Therefore, I decided to use the datareport